# Image won't resize with browser size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have an image next to some text. I want it to be vertically centered with the text but offset to the left so it isn't overlapping the text.  I can achieve this but whenever I resize my browser and make it smaller the image does not move.

I have tried putting the text within the text but whenever I do that the text doesn't center properly.  I also have to add a link underneath the image so I don't think this is the best way to go.

Here is a JSBin of the problem with my code: http://jsbin.com/evasix/2/ **I included my full code in the jsbing because I think something may be being inherited by another div class.

HTML:

```
<div class="middle">
    <div class="side-img">
        <h2>Millions of entrepreneurs, freelancers, small<br>businesses, and departments inside big<br> organizations rely on our web apps.</h2>
        <img src="images/img-customerss.png" class="customers">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #232323;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    line-height: 50px;
}


.customers {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 425px;
}
```

Comment: I see no code (CSS not HTML) whatsoever to size the image. Why do you think it should?

Comment: I can't view re link but have you tried using percentages instead of fixed pixel sizes? Firebug helps a lot with that type of thing

Comment: I am not sure why the link isn't working, it seems to be working fine. No, I didn't add a size for the image since the image is the size I want it to be.  I haven't fiddled with percentages yet, do you mean change the bottom/top px values to percentages?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using pixel distances from the edges. A pixel is a fixed size, and resizing your window wont cause it to adapt. Try using another unit of measurement such as `%`.

Hope it helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines

http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/3/

html:

```
    <div id="content1">
        <ul class="tmo_list">
                <strong>
          Commercial Buildings<br><br>
          Shopping Centers<br><br>
          Dumpster Pads<br><br>
          Decks & Patio<br><br>
          Store Fronts<br><br>
          Restaurants<br><br>
          Drive Ways<br><br>
          Awnings<br><br>
                </strong>
            </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="imageCol">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="http://theclassroomkit.com/images/link_icons/literacylinks/starfall-abc.gif"/>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="content2">
            <strong>
          Office Buildings<br><br>
          Business Signs<br><br>
          Loading Docks<br><br>
          Rust Removal<br><br>
          Wood Fences<br><br>
          Gas Stations<br><br>
          Bus Stops<br><br>
          Homes<br><br>
                </strong>
            </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content1 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}

#imageCol {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

#content2 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}


.wrapper img {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
```